Very strange behavior of System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize
    public class StagingModel
    {
        public string? TableName { get; set; }
        public string? ConnectionName { get; set; }
        public long? TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object>? Data { get; set; } = [];
    }

StagingModel stagingModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StagingModel>(message);

Here is JSON String for reproduction:
{
  "TableName":"position",
  "ConnectionName":"TestDat",
  "Timestamp":1708538002240,
  "Data":{
    "gpslatitude":54.719564167,
    "gpslongitude":11.448629
  },
  "TopicName":"kafka"
}

Above is my model which is deserialize into StagingModel, "System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize" is deserialized "TimeStamp" property and the value is null.
At the same time "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject" is deserialized the same string and the value of "TimeStamp property" is not null.


"TimeStamp" (uppercase S) is not the same as "Timestamp" (lowercase s)

@phuzi Thanks for pointing out. This is correct finding but Newtonsoft is converting correctly. Sometime it is converting correctly not all times.  I have few cases where it was working with Capital S as well.

I would be surprised if the issue was Json.Net. It's more likely that you have 2 different classes with the difference in property names or using different settings when serializing. Try replicating the issue in a small console app. If it's still an issue it would be a separate question though.

@phuzi I have one class with the same property name. I will try to replicate it today and will share the code with you.
